# Ng repeat not working in kenwheeler - Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I am using [kenwheeler](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slick carousel but when I use `ng-repeat` on the div i get `listed images'.

What I a doing wrong here ?

```
<section class="regular slider" style="clear: both" ng-if="slides">
  <div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
    <img src="{{slide.path}}">
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried the solutions provided here [angular slick](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/issues/2) although its different but still no proper images are being displayed. without `ng-repeat` it works perfect.

The output is something like this [image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1734769/3162502/f49ff416-eb35-11e3-8f47-3a85f8abfd84.png)

My controller

```
$scope.single_product = function (product_id) {
        $http.get('abc',
                {headers:
                            {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                'Authorization': $rootScope.keyword_auth_token}
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.product = data;
                    $(".regular").slick({
                        dots: true,
                        infinite: true,
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 3,
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplaySpeed: 2000
                    });
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
    };
```

I am including `slick.css` `slick-theme.css` and `slick.js`here is the link to all [Files](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/tree/master/slick)

Comment: can u give us a plunker

Comment: no error bro and I cant give you plunker man

Comment: You are able to get images but in a list right? Not side by side?

Comment: try ng-src = "{{slide.path}}"

Comment: Can u share some code which actually contains your controller?

Comment: listed images means what?

Comment: see the iamge which i uploaded dear

Comment: have you referenced slick.js in index??

Comment: Yes I have refereneced it in index thats why it was working fine but when i use ng repeat it fails

Comment: My controller has nothing i am getting the data and then I am calling this slick carousel

Comment: do u want the image to appear like slide from left to right?

Comment: yes i want the image to appear like slide from left to righ

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `src` Use `ng-src` ng-src use to get the path of image in angularJS

Comment: did it before no success

Answer (score 1):

Go through this link carefully and apply styles 
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

remove `div` that contains `ng-repeat`

```
<section class="regular slider" style="clear: both" ng-if="slides">
    <img ng-repeat="slide in slides" ng-src="{{slide.path}}">
</section>
```

Comment: I told in my question there is no css issue, I get listed images only when i apply ng repeat otherwise its perfecto

Comment: still the same output

Comment: Please include all styles.css and js source files that are related to slick

Comment: see the files please

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.slides = [{
    path: 'https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1734769/3162502/f49ff416-eb35-11e3-8f47-3a85f8abfd84.png'
  }, {
    path: 'https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1734769/3162502/f49ff416-eb35-11e3-8f47-3a85f8abfd84.png'
  }, {
    path: 'https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1734769/3162502/f49ff416-eb35-11e3-8f47-3a85f8abfd84.png'
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <section class="regular slider" style="clear: both" ng-if="slides">
    <div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
      <img ng-src="{{slide.path}}">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
  <img ng-src="slide.path">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check angular-slick [README](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick) and include all css and js. Add `slick` to your `angular.module` [ let say `MyApp` ] dependency and use `slick` directives. I think you missed to use `slick` directives.

```
<section class="regular slider" style="clear: both" ng-if="slides">
  <slick slides-to-show=3 slides-to-scroll=3>
    <div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
      <img src="{{slide.path}}">
    </div>
  </slick>
</section>
```

Comment: I am not using angular js slick man i am using the slick which I have mentioned in my question